# How to populate a SQL in query

Tags: string, bash

I have a generic SQL query that I'd like to use bash to populate all of the rows with from a grep command that I get the strings from. The amount of strings that I get from the file I am pulling the strings from varies as well.

Example query:

```
    select * from table_name
    where column_name in ('string',
    'string',
    'string',
    'string',
    'string',
    'string',
    'string',)
```

Basically I am looking at email message IDs and I get an output of message IDs. One string per line.

```
grep -Eoh "[a-z0-9]{0,9}\.0\.[0-9]{0,9}\.00\-[0-9]{0,9}\.[0-9]{0,9}\.[a-z0-9{0,10}\.hostname.com" *filename.txt 

62e60645.0.2279968.00-2316.3908868.d02c12m066.hostname.com
3ebe0645.0.522591.00-2200.908364.a02c11m025.hostname.com
356f0645.0.1401456.00-2085.2306795.g02c12m014.hostname.com
9a001645.0.1594149.00-1533.2646910.y01c12m093.hostname.com
```

and so on.

What I would like to do is have all of the strings from my grep command automatically inserted in to the query so I can simply paste the string in and run in.

Comment: The output from your grep command contains the strings that need to be in that sql query?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo 'select * from table_name where column_name in ('"$(grep -Eoh '[a-z0-9]{0,9}\.0\.[0-9]{0,9}\.00\-[0-9]{0,9}\.[0-9]{0,9}\.[a-z0-9]{0,10}\.hostname.com' *filename.txt | awk -v ORS=', ' '{print "\047"$0"\047"}')"')'
select * from table_name where column_name in ('62e60645.0.2279968.00-2316.3908868.d02c12m066.hostname.com', '3ebe0645.0.522591.00-2200.908364.a02c11m025.hostname.com', '356f0645.0.1401456.00-2085.2306795.g02c12m014.hostname.com', '9a001645.0.1594149.00-1533.2646910.y01c12m093.hostname.com', )
```

Fixed a typo in your grep regex. You missed a closing `]` on the last range.

The internal awk command does the line-to-list formatting.

```
awk -v ORS=', ' '{print "\047"$0"\047"}')"'
```

`-v ORS=', '` set `ORS` (the output record separator to `,`)

`{print "\047"$0"\047"}` print each line with `'` before and after it with the value of `ORS` added at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can also accomplish it by iterating line by line and echoing:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'select * from table_name where column_name in ('
{
    read
    echo -n "'$REPLY'"
    while read; do
        echo -ne ",\n'$REPLY'"
    done
} < <(grep -Eoh '[a-z0-9]{0,9}\.0\.[0-9]{0,9}\.00\-[0-9]{0,9}\.[0-9]{0,9}\.[a-z0-9]{0,10}\.hostname.com' *filename.txt)
echo ')'
```

Here `$REPLY` contains the read lines (one by one) from the input provided by the [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) (`<(grep ...)`).